# Performance - ZF1 Optimize for high traffic

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework

I am using ZEND Framework1. It will render time to be slow. How to improve the performance?

Comment: If you provided us some information we might be able to help. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

1 - Take a look at the query generated and optimize them for example instead of using "select * " you select just columns you need .

2 - Create index in the database for columns you use a lot in search...

3- Also you can use an other level is the caching system , you can use memcache server .

4- Check if there is a cache componenent , i don't know for zend1 but in zend2 there are too many caching level ; here are some many links :

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.cache.html

[Zend how to use cache component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263696/zend-how-to-use-cache-component)

Hope it helps.